# Eigenvectors of algebraic group representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, terminology, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905053)
of Kollar and Szabo there is a lemma (Lemma $1$) in which the following terminology is used: "Every representation $H\rightarrow GL(n,K)$ has an $H$-eigenvector" ($H$ is an algebraic group).

I'm really sorry if my question is something well-known, but could you explain what "$H$-eigenvector" exactly means?

Comment: If I were to venture a guess, I'd say it's a common eigenvector for the image of the representation.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew said: an eigenvalue of a representation $\pi:H\to GL(n,K)$ is a vector $v$ which is an eigenvector of $\pi(g)$ for all $g\in H$. More precisely, one has $\pi(g)v=\chi(g)v$ where $\chi: H\to K^{\times}$ is some group homomorphism.